# Stack trace error with array as argument

Tags: c

I want to modify a single random element in an array of chars, which include `'0'`, `'1'`, and `'2'`. Only the `'0'`'s can be modified, which is why I first put their indexes in another array (if there is a way to do this more efficiently, I'd gladly change it).

However, I get a

```
cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace
```

I know the problem comes from this function

```
void ai_move(char (*array)[10])
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    unsigned char* possible_indexes = {0};
    int cpt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATASIZE - 1; ++i)
        if ((*array)[i] == '0')
        {
            possible_indexes[cpt] = i;
            ++cpt;
        }
    int rand_index = rand() % (sizeof(possible_indexes) - 1);
    (*array)[possible_indexes[rand_index]] = '1';
}
```

which I call like this:

```
ai_move(&grid);
```

`grid` contains the char array I want to modify, and is defined as:

```
char grid[MAXDATASIZE] = {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
```

I know the problem might come from the way I give `grid` as an argument, but after hours of searching I couldn't find a solution that would change anything.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: are you sure that the length of your array is equal to MAXDATASIZE?

Comment: You're probably getting a segfault when trying to access `possible_indexes[cpt]` since `possible_indexes` contains only one value

Comment: Your grid array only has 9 entries. What is MAXDATASIZE? Is it 10?

Comment: This function is used in a server, and `MAXDATASIZE` is the size of the grid I want to send. I read that I have to add `'\0'` at the end of the grid, which is why it is bigger than the actual grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned char* possible_indexes = {0};
```

Well , you declare a pointer but you don't allocate enough memory to it    (*precisely you don't even allocate memory*), and try to write at invalid location at later iterations.

```
 possible_indexes[cpt] = i;
```

Either allocate memory to `possible_indexes` first and then try to write or declare it as an array with desirable size.

**Note** -Also regarding `sizeof(possible_indexed)` in this -

```
  int rand_index = rand() % (sizeof(possible_indexes) - 1);
```

which will give size of pointer and not what would normally be desired i.e number of elements.

Comment: I first declared it as `unsigned char* possible_indexes;`. Would that work ?

Comment: @Blublublub No . If you declare it as pointer then allocate memory using `malloc` , or declare as array `unsigned char possible_indexes[50]` .

Comment: I see. I will declare it as unsigned char possible_indexes[9], as it is the max size. How then would I modify its size to the actual size it will have ?

Comment: @Blublublub See, if you need to modify its size later in program then better use `malloc` and reallocate memory using `realloc` function .

Comment: @Blublublub Gald it could help.